# Government performance (in) .. Is it the right preposition?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

I am writing a title for a research paper on the political effects of exposure to a governmental media campaign, on young people's attitudes toward the government efforts, and its capacity in the field of economic development.

This is my proposed title to the paper:

> The impact of exposure to "Hayah Karima" campaign on TV & Internet on youth's attitudes towards government's performance in development.

The question here is about the use of "performance" with the preposition "in". Is it right to say: Government's performance *in* development or *at* development? Should I use "performance in the field of development" or I can just simply put it as "performance in/at development"?

Comment: It may depend on what you mean by *development* and may depend on local usage. In the UK, it would not be a natural phrase, and if used might be interpreted as the application of overseas aid.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. the development here refers to the economic development or community development to raise the standards of living.

Comment: I offer a bit of an artistic re-write for you, as that is my forte - 'Is life better now - or not?' - how youth's perspectives on government were affected by the Hayah Karima media campaign on TV and the internet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable contribution dear Jelila. I appreciate it so much.

Comment: When I was younger, I never understood why older people used *youth* as collective noun.  I preferred *young people*.

Comment: The obvious Question is not what you thought to ask, but how either Question or exposition could work at, presumably, university level in English…

If you composed Question or exposition in English, I greatly admire your language skills yet if you composed them in another language and translated them to English, I suggest you seek a better translator.

More…

Comment: Further… Both 'The political effects of exposure to a governmental media campaign, on young people's attitudes toward the government efforts, and its capacity in the field of economic development' and 'The impact of exposure to "Hayah Karima" campaign on TV & Internet on youth's attitudes towards government's performance in development' beg more questions than they answer.

I still see both as bold and admirable efforts from any non-native speaker, and that both are comprehensible, yet I still think both fail as advanced English.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly, you need either just 'government efforts' or 'the government's efforts' if you're discussing a single government. If you're comparing more than one government, you might need 'the (various) governments' efforts.'

Both might be correct and why, please, are you using 'governmental…' rather than just 'government media campaign'?

Meanwhile '… attitudes toward the government efforts, and its capacity in the field of economic development…' is either tautological or simply too complicated.

If the people's attitudes are toward both the government efforts and its capacity then it's tautological.

If the people's attitudes are separately toward either the government efforts or its capacity, then it's too complicated.